# save the state of a bool so that when the application is run again, that state has been saved

Tags: windows-phone-7

While running my application the user has the possibility to show or hide a canvas so that they can see data set A or data set B. When they leave the program though and re-enter it at a later date. The application disregards what the user had pressed the button to see the canvas with data B on and instead reloads the application with data A. Like it would if the application had been run for the first time.

So what i want is a way so that when i close the application, it saves the fact that the button had been pressed to show the canvas, so that when the user goes back to it, the application will load with data set B showing.

the way i thought to do this was to set a global bool at the top of the page and have it so when the button is pressed the bool is set to true, then when the application is run again it checks for the state of that bool being true of false and loads the canvas which has the respective data set. However this did not work out. Is there any way to save this?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings, look here for some samples

1. http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings
2. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198869-wp7-using-isolatedstoragesettings/

Hope this helps!